# sklearn LinearRegression fitted with PolynomialFeatures not predicting correctly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Why is the predicted data not quadratic and not fitting the data it was trained on properly? It appears to not be scaled to the graph correctly and also it's not quadratic. What am I missing and doing wrong here?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

import yfinance as yf
import talib as ta

df = yf.download('TSLA',start='2019-01-01',end='2022-02-01',auto_adjust=True,progress=False)

df['rsi'] = ta.RSI(df['Close'])
df['adx'] = ta.ADX(df['High'],df['Low'],df['Close'])
df['lag'] = df['Close'].pct_change()
df['close'] = (df[['Close']].pct_change()+1).cumprod()
df['target'] = df['close'].shift(-10)
df.drop(['Open','High','Low','Close','Volume'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

y = df['target'].values
X = df.drop(['target','close'],axis=1).values

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.plot(y)
plt.grid()
plt.tick_params(colors='white')
```

[image: graph]

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=1, include_bias=False)
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_poly)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, y, test_size=.3,shuffle=False)

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = lr.predict(X_train)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.grid()
ax.tick_params(colors='white')
ax.plot(y_train)
ax.plot(y_pred, color='red',ls='--')
```

[image]

Comment: Your model apparently doesn't fit very well.  I am curious to know if you increase the `degree` of `PolynomialFeatures`, does the model fit better?

Comment: remove scaler = StandardScaler() from the pipeline.   It is changing the pct_change accum results

Answer (score 0):

Try using PolyFeatures with LinearRegression.  I use three curve fitting algorithms to visualize trend for dividends

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import datetime
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as sm
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn import linear_model


df=pd.read_csv("TSLA_5Y.csv",parse_dates=["Date"])
df['Close']=df['Close'].astype(float)
df.set_index("Date",inplace=True)

    
filter=((df.index >'2019-01-01') & (df.index<='2022-02-01'))
df=df[filter]

df['close_accum'] = (df[['Close']].pct_change()+1).cumprod()

df['close_accum']=df['close_accum'].astype(float)

df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
df = df.dropna()
df = df.reset_index() 



  def func(params, x):
    a, b, c = params
    return a * x * x + b * x + c


# Error function, that is, the difference between the value obtained by fitting curve and the actual value
def error(params, x, y):
    return func(params, x) - y


def parabolicTrend(inputX,inputY):
    p0 = [10, 10, 10]
    Para = leastsq(error, p0, args=(inputX, inputY))
    return Para

days_in_future = 10
future_forecast = np.array([i for i in range(len(df)+days_in_future)]).reshape(-1, 1)
adjusted_range = future_forecast[:-10]

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(adjusted_range, df['close_accum'].values)


SEED=42
gbt=GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=300, max_depth=1, random_state=SEED)
gbt.fit(adjusted_range, df['close_accum'])  

Para = parabolicTrend(adjusted_range.flatten(),df['close_accum'].values)
a, b, c = Para[0]
x = future_forecast
y = a * x * x + b * x + c # # function

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))
plt.plot(adjusted_range, df['close_accum'])
plt.plot(future_forecast,gbt.predict(future_forecast),c="red") #gbtboostingregressor
plt.plot(future_forecast,model.predict(future_forecast),c="green") #linear regressor
plt.plot(x,y,color="purple",label="solution line",linewidth=2)

plt.title('Tesla growth Over Time', size=30)
plt.xlabel('Time', size=30)
plt.ylabel('Growth pct', size=30)
plt.legend(['Growth pct', 'Predictions'], prop={'size': 20})
plt.xticks(size=20)
plt.yticks(size=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
df = df.dropna()
df = df.reset_index()    make sure to remove the nan values created by pct_change

Answer (score 0):

try arma

```
df=pd.read_csv("TSLA_5Y.csv",parse_dates=["Date"])
df.set_index("Date",inplace=True)
filter=((df.index >'2019-01-01') & (df.index<='2022-02-01'))
df=df[filter]

df['close_accum'] = (df[['Close']].pct_change()+1).cumprod()
print("Predicted Price pct change")
def plotARMA(df_accumulative,ax,label):
    result=df_accumulative
    result=result.rolling(window=45).mean().dropna()
    mod = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(result, order=(2,0,0))
    res = mod.fit()
    # Plot the original series and the forecasted series
    #res.plot_predict(start=0, end=400)
    df_accumulative.plot(ax=ax,label=label)
    res.predict().plot(ax=ax,label=label)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))    
plotARMA(df['close_accum'] ,ax,"Tesla")
plt.legend(fontsize=8)
plt.title("ARMA")
plt.show()
```